# Which One did we get?

Tags: sliders

Sliders 2x08 Post Traumatic Slide Syndrome at the end we see 2 Prof. Maximilian Arturo's fighting it out for who was going to slide, When one of them is able to jump leaving the other behind. The one left behind says "Oh My God" in shock implying  that the one who jumped is very likely not in fact their Prof. Maximilian Arturo.

It seems this is never covered again, or I missed it. Who jumped through the portal?